# BlockingQueue drainTo and add - multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following case:

- Multiple threads are calling, regularly, the `add(E e)` function.
- A thread which runs at every second and call `int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c)`.

As I have read about, that `add` and `drain-To`, separately, are thread-safe. But I am not sure in the case when are running in parallel.

I docs, about `drainTo` is saying this:

> Removes all available elements from this queue and adds them to the given collection. This operation may be more efficient than repeatedly polling this queue. **A failure encountered while attempting to add elements to collection c may result in elements being in neither, either or both collections when the associated exception is thrown.** Attempts to drain a queue to itself result in IllegalArgumentException. Further, the behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress.

What I understand from here is that using `add` during `drainTo` will result in failure.

I am understanding it right? If yes, can someone suggest me a solution for my case?

Comment: When running in parallel it should still be thread safe? The underlying internal implementation of blockingqueues uses reentrantlocks which should prevent the methods from executing at the same time

Comment: The javadoc says _the behavior of this operation is undefined if **the specified collection** is modified while the operation is in progress_. The specified collection is the collection that is passed as argument. If it would mean the blocking queue it would say _if this blocking queue is modified_.

Comment: Looking at the implementation of `LinkedBlockingDeque`, looks like both methods `add` and `drainTo` use the same lock, so in theory it shouldn't fail when you use them in parallel. Take a look on your desired implementation source code.

Comment: There is no such thing as being “separately thread safe”. Being thread safe implies that calling them from different threads, potentially at the same time, is permitted. Otherwise, it wouldn’t be thread safe. As Thomas Kläger said, this statement is not referring to the blocking queue. Read again, especially the phrase “*to add elements to collection c*”. Collection `c` is not the blocking queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Doc refers to sink, not source

You’ve misread the documentation.

The “given collection” is the destination collection into which you are draining elements, not the queue from which you are draining.

So you are responsible for:

- Verifying that your “given collection” (the sink) can accept the elements being drained from the queue (the source).
- Ensuring your “given collection” (the sink) is not modified during the draining.

Since `BlockingQueue` is documented as being thread-safe, you can add and drain at the same time across threads.